# Java containers of generic types

Tags: java, generics

I am preparing for an exam and one of the codes we were given by professor is obscure to me:

```
public class Z {

    static java.util.LinkedList<? extends Object> a =
            new java.util.LinkedList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a.add(null); // 1
        a.add(new Object()); // 2
        a.add("new Object()"); // 3
        System.out.println(a); // 4
    }
}
```

NetBeans gives me really strange compilation errors here:

```
no suitable method found for add(java.lang.Object)
method java.util.LinkedList.add(capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object) is not applicable
(actual argument java.lang.Object cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object by method invocation conversion)

no suitable method found for add(java.lang.String)
method java.util.LinkedList.add(capture#2 of ? extends java.lang.Object) is not applicable
(actual argument java.lang.String cannot be converted to capture#2 of ? extends java.lang.Object by method invocation conversion)
```

Could anyone please explain me these errors? I was pretty sure that it should be possible to add String objects to this list.

Comment: Is that meant to be "and ladies"? ;)

Answer (score 9):

PECS - Producer extends, Consumer super - this is a mnemonic proposed by Bloch to cope with the above.

In other words, if you use `extends` you can only produce elements from your collection. If you want it to consume elements - use `super`.

The point of that is to enforce compile-time safety. If your collection was defined with `? extends SomeBaseClass`, this would mean "It can contain instances of a single subclass of the base class". In your case you are defining  `new LinkedList<String>()`, but you try to add an `Object` - this should not be allowed, and it is caught by the compiler.

Comment: Actually, it's showing a compiler error on line `a.add("new Object()");` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bozho, but it doesn't explain why it shows compilation error in "add("new Object()");" line, even though it adds a String object

Comment: @Maciej you cannot add anything to that collection. because it is defined only to produce elements.

Answer (score 5):

When calling `a.add()`, java only knows you call add on `java.util.LinkedList<? extends Object>`. The linked list with `String` is unknown at that point. You could have added another linked list with any other type on a previous line.

All java knows is that the list contains something that `extends Object`. This could be anything since every class in java extends object.

```
a = new java.util.LinkedList<Object>();  // valid
a = new java.util.LinkedList<Integer>();  // valid
a = new java.util.LinkedList<java.util.zip.Checksum>();  // valid
```

Notice that since `a` can contain any linked list, you can not add anything to it. If you add a `Object`, the list could be expecting `Integer`. If you add a `Integer`, it could be expecting `Checksum`.

You have the same problem is you write

```
static java.util.LinkedList<? extends Number> b = new java.util.LinkedList<Integer>();
```

and then:

```
b.add(new Float(10.0f)); // fails
b.add(new Integer(10)); // fails
```

Java still wouldn't know if the list contains Floats or Integers, so it forbid both.

The correct way to declare the list would be:

```
static java.util.LinkedList<? super Number> c = new java.util.LinkedList<Number>(); // valid
static java.util.LinkedList<? super Number> c = new java.util.LinkedList<Object>(); // valid
```

The following code would now fail:

```
static java.util.LinkedList<? super Number> c = new java.util.LinkedList<Integer>(); // fails
```

because `c` can't contain `List<Integer>` now, adding a `Float` will be valid.

Edit:
To get back to the original example. There is a somewhat evil way how to use the add function on a `List<? extends Object>`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       a.add(null); // 1
        ((List<Object>)a).add(new Object()); // 2
        ((List<Object>)a).add("new Object()"); // 3
        System.out.println(a); // 4
}
```

Notice 2 and 3 will give a unchecked cast warning. You risk [heap pollution](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/non-reifiable-varargs-type.html), in fact, case 2 does exactly that.

Answer (score 4):

What `LinkedList<? extends Object>` means is "a linked list that can contain only members of some specific *unknown* class that extends `Object`", so it's the same as `LinkedList<?>`. Since it's unknown *which* class is the one in question, you cannot add anything to such a list.

If you want to have a list that can contain members of *any* class, use `LinkedList<Object>`.

Answer (score 2):

By have `LinkedList<? extends Object> a`, the linked list **isn't bound** to a type `T` since it's wildcarded to an *unknown* that extends object.

Hence when doing `a.add()`, the parameterized type is *unknown* and thus it translates it as `a.add(null)`. It types the unknown as `null`. It means you cannot add anything to the unknown type.

Your `//1` is acceptable (as described above) but for `//2` and `//3` is ambiguous.

The reason of the errors is because it's trying to do a [Method Invocation Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#12687) to an unknown type and since we don't know the *unknown* that `extends` the `Object`, it can't do a conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
So, i understand, that by declaring `LinkedList<? extends AnythingYouCanThinkOf> = new LinkedList<AnyClass>()` I just create List, that nothing can be added to?

Comment: Yes, as you're using a wildcard `?`. If you want to be specific, **bound** your list to a type.